# JWT Authentication ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt

I've seen numerous examples of how to use JWT authentication with Angular, React, Vue etc... clients but can't find any examples of using JWT authentication with ASP.NET Core (specifically 2.2) Web App Mvc.

Does anyone have any examples or advice on how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/

Comment: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: see also https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and help provided, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use this class based on nuget package JWT 3.0.3

```
using JWT;
using JWT.Algorithms;
using JWT.Serializers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace Common.Utils
{
  public class JwtToken
  {
    private IJwtEncoder encoder;
    private IJwtDecoder decoder;

    /// <remarks>
    /// This requires a key value randomly generated and stored in your configuration settings. 
    /// Consider that it is a good practice use keys as at least long as the output digest bytes 
    /// length produced by the hashing algorithm used. Since we use an HMAC-SHA-512 algorithm, 
    /// then we can provide it a key at least 64 bytes long.
    /// <see cref="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4868#page-7"/>
    /// </remarks>
    public string SecretKey { get; set; } 

    public JwtToken()
    {
        IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA512Algorithm();
        IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
        IDateTimeProvider datetimeProvider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
        IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, datetimeProvider);
        IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();

        encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);
        decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder);
        SecretKey = "";
    }

    public JwtToken(string secretKey) : this()
    {
        SecretKey = secretKey;
    }

    public bool IsTokenValid(string token)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DecodeToken(token));
    }

    public string GetToken(object payload)
    {
        try
        {
            return encoder.Encode(payload, SecretKey);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return encoder.Encode(new DataModel(payload), SecretKey);
        }
    }

    public string DecodeToken(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token) || token == "null")
            {
                return null;
            }
            return decoder.Decode(token, SecretKey, true);
        }
        catch (TokenExpiredException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (SignatureVerificationException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public T DecodeToken<T>(string token) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return decoder.DecodeToObject<T>(token, SecretKey, true);
        }
        catch (TokenExpiredException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (SignatureVerificationException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var data = decoder.DecodeToObject<DataModel>(token, SecretKey, true).Data;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        }
    }
  }

  public class DataModel
  {
    public DataModel(object data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
    public object Data { get; set; }
  }
}
```

> Then in your `Startup` class `Configure` method set the jwt middleware
>   for check authentication status of each request:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
        {

            // verify app access token if not another service call
            var appAccessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (appAccessToken.Count == 0)
            {
                context.Items["User"] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                var token = appAccessToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
                var jwtToken = new JwtToken(config.JwtTokenSecret); //you need a secret (with requirements specified above) in your configuration (db, appsettings.json)
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token) || !jwtToken.IsTokenValid(token))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }

                dynamic user = jwtToken.DecodeToken<dynamic>(token);

                var cachedToken = cache.Get(user.Id);  //you need some cache for store your token after login success and so can check against
                if (cachedToken == null || cachedToken.ToString() != token)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }

                context.Items["User"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "FullName",user.Name?.ToString()},
                        { "FirstName",user.FirstName?.ToString()},
                        { "LastName",user.LastName?.ToString()},
                        { "Role",user.Role?.ToString()},
                        { "Email",user.Email?.ToString()}
                    };
            }
            return next();
        });
```

> And finally you need generate the token and return it after
>   authentication:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        User user = null; //you need some User class with the structure of the previous dictionary
        if (checkAuthenticationOK(username, password, out user)) //chackAuthenticationOk sets the user against db data after a succesfull authentication
        {
           var token = new JwtToken(_config.JwtTokenSecret).GetToken(user);  //_config is an object to your configuration
           _cache.Set(user.id, token);  //store in the cache the token for checking in each request
           return Ok(token);
        }

        return StatusCode(401, "User is not authorized");
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Can you explain _cache a bit more? Feel free to point me to existing article.

Comment: Hi, as far as concern the cache, as you can read in the comments accompanying the code, you need some mechanism that implements it. Feel free to use the cache libraries you prefer. For Asp.Net Core you could use the very good  Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory by implementing IMemoryCache interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1, for Asp.Net you could use System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache object: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: All of these examples that I've seen show how to generate token, and return token to client.. and its usually sent back in the authorization header.. that's great for web apps that would hit your webapi.. but none of the tutorials explain for a regular mvc app how to use that token? Like do you take the token via javascript and inject it into the header of all subsequent request? (Pita) Or do you attach it as a cookie? Or does .net handle all this and I'm missing something?.. I follow tutorials.. identity was working fine until I added the jwt stuff.. now no logins work. No token in header

Comment: What will redirect to the Login method if the token is not in the header? Thanks.

Comment: @RajeevMenon you have to implement the redirect in your SPA app

Answer (score 1):

**Add following code to startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["SigningKey"]))
                };
            });

    }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
   app.UseAuthentication();

}
```

**Code for login action in AccountController**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = _userService.Authenticate(loginViewModel);


        var claims = new[]
        {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, loginViewModel.Username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                };

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken
                    (
                        issuer: _configuration["Issuer"],
                        audience: _configuration["Audience"],
                        claims: claims,
                        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10),
                        notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["SigningKey"])),
                             SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                    );

        return Ok(new
        {
            access_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
            expires_in = (int)token.ValidTo.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalSeconds,// TimeSpan.FromTicks( token.ValidTo.Ticks).TotalSeconds,
            sub = loginViewModel.Username,
            name = loginViewModel.Username,
            fullName = user.FullName,
            jobtitle = string.Empty,
            phone = string.Empty,
            email = user.EmailName,

        });
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That really works in API project. But what if pure MVC html project? I mean, without JavaScript, how can the token be inserted to the request authentication header? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have implemented JWT on the server side. To handle this on client side, first you have to add token to web browser local storage. Add to your main layout javascript (let's named it AuthService.js)

> below code adds token to local storage after login button clicked. `gettokenfromlocalstorage()` retrieve token from local storage.

```
<script>
var token = "";
function Loginclick() {
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var data = new FormData(form);
    var authsevice = new AuthService();
    authsevice.LogIn(data.get("username").toString(), data.get("password").toString());
}
function gettokenfromlocalstorage() {
    var authserv = new AuthService();
    var mytoken = authserv.getAuth();
    authserv.LogOut();
}
var AuthService = /** @class */ (function () {
    function AuthService() {
        this.authKey = "auth";
    }
    AuthService.prototype.LogIn = function (username, password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.grant_type = "password";
        this.client_id = "MyClientId";
        var loginurl = "/api/Token/Auth";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", loginurl, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(this));
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log("onreadystatechange");
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            var aaa = this.responseText;
        };
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var auth = new AuthService();
            auth.setAuth(data);
        };
    };
    AuthService.prototype.LogOut = function () {
        this.setAuth(null);
        return true;
    };
    AuthService.prototype.setAuth = function (auth) {
        if (auth) {
            localStorage.setItem(this.authKey, JSON.stringify(auth));
        }
        else {
            localStorage.removeItem(this.authKey);
        }
        return true;
    };
    AuthService.prototype.getAuth = function () {
        var i = localStorage.getItem(this.authKey);
        return i === null ? null : JSON.parse(i);
    };
    AuthService.prototype.isLoggedIn = function () {
        return localStorage.getItem(this.authKey) !== null ? true : false;
    };
    return AuthService;
}());
var aa = new AuthService();
var gettoken = aa.getAuth();
if (gettoken !== null) {
    token = gettoken.token;
}
</script>
```

> To add token to the header of each anchor tag put below script also to
> your main layout.

```
<script>
var links = $('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {  
    links[i].onclick = function check() {
        addheader(this.href);
        return false;
    }
}

function addheader(object) {
  
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", object, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        window.history.pushState("/", "", xhr.responseURL);
        //mycontainer is a div for parialview content
        $("#mycontainer").html(xhr.responseText);
        window.onpopstate = function (e) {
            if (e.state) {
                $("html").html = e.state;
                document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
            }
        };
     
    };

}
</script>
```

Remember that using of this approach, each view has to be loaded as a partial view.
If you insert url address in a web browser bar directly this solution doesn't work. I haven't figured it out yet. That's why to manage token authentication is better using single page application, not multipage application.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly need to import the required packages for using authentication.The packages we need to import are

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
using System.Text;
```

After importing the required packages we need to configure the authentication service for using jwt Tokens.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:5001",
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:4200",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my secret key"))
     };
  })
```

As to make our authentication middleware available to our application,we need to make one more step

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Here Ensure that we need to use these middleware in the same order like it declared above.

These are the steps required to configure the jwt authentication in asp.net core web api.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this boilerplate](https://github.com/AlexanderAnishchik/ASP-Core-API-Template) to understand how to implement JWT tokenization with .Net Core. In the project you can find JWT, Swagger and EF features.

Comment: OP is asking about an MVC project, your link is for a Web API